# New version of the Nuget package - how to check that it's already available?

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to download a package I've recently pushed to the Nuget server (downloading via Nuget.Core library). The package info has IsListed() set to true, but I'm getting a "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." exception; this problem happens every time I push a new version of my package, and disappears after a few minutes.
So, how do I check that the new version of the package is **really** available for download?